# After disabling and reenabling wifi, can't reconnect

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I disabled WiFi on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine to double check that some files I needed would be available offline later. After reenabling WiFi, I was unable to reconnect to my wireless network. I've tried restarting, disabling/enabling networking, rfkill block/unblock wifi, and a couple other suggestions I've found on the forums. This happens pretty frequently. Whenever I disable WiFi and then reenable it, I often have trouble reconnecting. I haven't been able to land on a set of steps that works consistently. As far as I can tell, it reconnects at random whenever it's good and ready.

Does anyone know a consistent set of steps I can take to reconnect when this happens? The cause is always the same, so I would think the solution should always be the same, as well.

**Requested Output**

Note that at the time I ran the script, I was not experiencing the issue. I had a successful and sustained connection.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 04 Mar 2015 19:58 EST -0500

Booted last: 04 Mar 2015 19:51 EST -0500

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-46-generic #77-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 2 18:26:13 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8170]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:f920]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f2:b446 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                172842  0 
mac80211              546067  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               152049  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              409394  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
wmi                    18673  1 toshiba_acpi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.8  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a288:69ff:fe7b:724e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24040 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:29008009 (29.0 MB)  TX bytes:3107248 (3.1 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"shayler"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'shayler' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=23/70  Signal level=-87 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:35  Invalid misc:1159   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: wlan0  [shayler] -----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           9 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    pipsgreeneyes:   Infra, <MAC 'pipsgreeneyes' [AN1]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 14 WPA2
    HP783F42:        Ad-Hoc, <MAC 'HP783F42' [AN2]>, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 11 Mb/s, Strength 19
    *shayler:        Infra, <MAC 'shayler' [AC1]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 33 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.8
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/freedompop-8990]] (600 root)
[connection] id=freedompop-8990 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=freedompop-8990 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SouthwestWiFi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SouthwestWiFi | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=SouthwestWiFi | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Moab]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Moab | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Moab | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Rasmussen family]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Rasmussen family | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Rasmussen family | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/shayler 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=shayler 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=shayler | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/shayler]] (600 root)
[connection] id=shayler | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=shayler | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/slytastic]] (600 root)
[connection] id=slytastic | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=slytastic | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

wlan0     32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency=2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### iwlist scan #######################

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'shayler' [AC1]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"shayler"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000003c50a2603c
                    Extra: Last beacon: 192ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-46-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     412FF07DA992AAD938A30BE
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-46-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        8E:EB:17:02:75:CF:3E:2A:62:50:43:18:01:98:A0:8B:B9:A0:B9:8A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-46-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     B8DF1ECC076C2FCEAC70533
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-46-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        8E:EB:17:02:75:CF:3E:2A:62:50:43:18:01:98:A0:8B:B9:A0:B9:8A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-46-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
srcversion:     B81BA270CF5925E724426BD
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-46-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        8E:EB:17:02:75:CF:3E:2A:62:50:43:18:01:98:A0:8B:B9:A0:B9:8A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable, 2=enable (default: 0) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-46-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     5C139B156678DB83EDA757D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-46-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        8E:EB:17:02:75:CF:3E:2A:62:50:43:18:01:98:A0:8B:B9:A0:B9:8A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 1

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 1
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 1
wd_disable: 1

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf]
options iwlmvm power_scheme=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=Y swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

rfkill block bluetooth
sleep 10
iwconfig wlan0 power off
exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x08b3 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   12.610792] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.24.8.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   12.640111] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   12.640168] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 2 times)
[   12.667077] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq
[   12.742343] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   12.771351] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[   16.053901] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 2 times)
[   16.065623] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   19.787066] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'shayler' [AC1]>
[   19.787807] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'shayler' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   19.820431] wlan0: authenticated
[   19.823778] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'shayler' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   19.831022] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'shayler' [AC1]> (capab=0x31 status=0 aid=5)
[   19.831510] wlan0: associated
[   19.831531] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

**Requested Output Pt. 2**

Lucked out (I guess) and had the problem again. Here's what the script produces when the wireless won't connect:

(Too many characters here, so had to paste it in the ubuntu pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10533647/)

Comment: Please run [diagnostic script](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/295286) and add output to your question